# Camera hotkey popup not displaying after update Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, display, camera

On my Lenovo laptop I have a button to activate/deactivate my camera, just as I do for increasing/decreasing brightness, volume, muting mic, enabling/disabling touchpad, etc.

The camera button still works, but I get not visual display to indicate the button was pressed, as I do for other buttons.

Ex. image for toggling mic:

[image: Mic Enabled]

And this is when I press it to disable:

[image: Mic Disabled]

However, when I press the one that corresponds to my camera it no longer shows the display. To be clear, the key still works as expected but no display.

I am not sure if I accidentally changed a setting or what happened, but the last time I tested it was about 9 days ago when I had a video interview, and it was working. Since then I believe I installed some updates, so I think they might have messed something up.